# VBA API REST - Returns Status 500

Tags: excel, vba, rest, api, request

I'm trying to connect to an API from a web-based tool.
Reading their documentation, I figured out how to send requests via VBA (Excel - Code Below).

- The tool gives me the `username` (aka token), `password` and the `authString` (aka Base64 encoded token)
- Running the code, commenting the `.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & token64` line returns `Status 401 - Unauthorized`.
- Running the code with the line `.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & token64` returns `Status 500 - Internal server Error`
- Asking the support team, they say to me that to get a response, I need to call a service, such as:

> {   "service": "company.list" }

My main objective here is to use VBA integration to pull some information via API to the tool, such as 'Projects', 'Customers', etc.

What am I doing wrong? Can you guys please help me to accomplish my objective, sending me tips/documentation to read?
Should I use another language but VBA (python, C#)?

Website API documentation:
https://beebole.com/timesheet-api/

## Code

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RESTtest()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim authString As String
    Dim aSync As String
    Dim token64 As String
    Dim project As String


        username = "username"
        password = "x"
        authString = username & ":" & password

        token64 = "usernameEncoded64"
        URL = "https://beebole-apps.com/api/v2"
        aSync = False


    Dim restRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim restResult As String

        Set restRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

  With restRequest
    .Open "POST", URL, aSync
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
    .SetRequestHeader "service", "company.list"
    .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & token64
    .Send
    .waitForResponse

    Debug.Print ".ResponseText: " & .ResponseText
    Debug.Print ".Status: " & .Status
    Debug.Print ".StatusText: " & .StatusText
    Debug.Print ".ResponseBody: " & .ResponseBody

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be a `GET` request?

Comment: If it is post request (looks like it is in the docs), you need to POST the JSON in the body of the request, not the header. e.g. don't do `.SetRequestHeader "service", "company.list"`, do this: `.Send "{ ""service"": ""company.list"" }"`

Comment: Seems based on their response that  they want to have the request encoded as a json object..but i can not see any curly braces in your request { - which simply means you do not send a JSON string. They provide a sample " {
  "service": "absence.list",
  "company" : {"id" : 233}
  }" so format your response string according the Javascript Object notation (and their sample) and send this. You currently just sent plain test. And this will mix up the server which send you a 500 (usually internal server error). No wonder the Javascript interpreter get  a mal formated string.

Comment: @Zac the support team said to me that they just accept HTTP POST. That's why I'm  using that.

Comment: "500 - not found" is weird. "not found" should be 404, 500 should be for an "internal server error". Add to that, that the API apparently wants a POST request to *get* things, and that's a REST API one would justifiably qualify as wrong. Your only hope is that their documentation is actually up-to-date and accurately documents how to use this weird, broken API. The problem is the API, not the language you use to make the request - the API will be just as awkward & wrong if you make the request in Java or Python.

Comment: @RyanWildry It works. Know it's kinda clear to me.

Do you have any documentation o something that I can read about it?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon you are right. The server returns "Status 500 - Internal Server Error". I will correct my post. Tks

Comment: You set `token64 = "usernameEncoded64"` - is this a "short hand" version of your actual encoding of your `authstring` or have you hard coded the API token they give you? The docs indicate that you need to use the API token as the username and `x` as the password, then `Base64Encode` that to insert into your `"Authorization"` header.

Comment: @FreeMan I put "usernameEncoded64" to not share the token that I'm using. I've tried both ways: Base64Encoding the key (username+":"+pass) and using their enconded key. Both works.